# When can we say that $\left\lceil\dfrac{\pi(m)}{\pi(\sqrt{m})}\right\rceil>\frac{\sqrt{m}}{3}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is in the title, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. We know that the asymptotic value of this ratio is $\frac{\sqrt m}2$, so it must cross $\frac{\sqrt m}3$ after some threshold, is there a way we can get a rough idea about this threshold? I do not know if there is some relation between $\pi(\sqrt m)$ and $\pi(m)$, so I couldn't get started with it.

Comment: it already works by $m=10000$

Comment: Yeah, @RoddyMacPhee, but how do we ensure that it works continuously later too? Since the ratio is perhaps not monotonic.

Comment: Yeah, @RoddyMacPhee, I've written that in my question. That means, after some threshold all the terms will be more than $\frac{\sqrt{m}}{3}$. But the fact that it is more than $\frac{\sqrt m}{3}$ for $m=10000$, doesn't mean the threshold is $10000$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia gives a few [non-asmyptotiv bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function), e.g.,
$$\tag1\frac x{\ln x+2}<\pi(x)<\frac x{\ln x -4} \qquad \text{for }x\ge 55$$
This makes
$$ \frac{\pi(x^2)}{\pi(x)}>\frac{\frac {x^2}{\ln x^2+2}}{\frac x{\ln x-4}}=\frac{x}{\frac{2\ln x+2}{\ln x-4}}=\frac x{2+\frac{10}{\ln x-4}}$$
and for the desired result, it suffices to make $x>e^{14}$, i.e., $$m>e^{28}$$ To explicitly respect the ceiling function, we should actually take $x>e^{14}+3$, i.e., $m>e^{28}+6e^{14}+9$, but instead of doing that we might use something better than $(1)$, a result by Dusart (2010):
$$\tag2\frac x{\ln x-1}<\pi(x)<\frac x{\ln x -1.1} \qquad \text{for }x\ge 60184.$$
This time, we find
$$ \frac{\pi(x^2)}{\pi(x)}>\frac{\frac{x^2}{\ln x^2-1}}{\frac{x}{\ln x-1.1}}=\frac {x}{\frac{2\ln x-1}{\ln x-1.1}}=\frac x{2+\frac{0.9}{\ln x-1.1}}>\frac x{2.1}\qquad \text{for }x\ge 60184.$$
Thus $$m>\left\lceil(60184+2.1)^2\right\rceil=3{,}622{,}366{,}634$$
is sufficient (and certainly small enough to check the "few" remaining $m$ manually).

Comment: Thank you, nice answer!